# Try to access user properties using User Profile REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am creating a SP designer workflow for my SharePoint Online site to get user properties like manager`s name, location, department etc. I am using below REST URL in 'Call HTTP Web Service' action

```
https:/siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v=%27i:0%23.f|membership|userid%27 .
```

I am a site collection admin but still I am getting error -

```
"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}"
```

I have already given  Full Control to workflow app. But when I access above REST URL in a browser, I can see all properties for any user.

Please let me know where am I doing a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workflow must have `tenant-level permissions(In your case-Read)` in order to access the User Profile Service instead of having full control at site collection

When giving rights make sure the following XML is used :

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Here are useful links

- https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint
- https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/sharepoint-2013-online-accessing-user-profile-properties-in-a-designer-workflow/

Comment: Here is the XML to use : `<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>`

Answer (score -1):

I created a workflow using SP 2010 workflow template available in SP designer 2013. In this template, I can directly query User Profile and get the desired properties from User Profile.
ref - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-start-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-within-a-sharepoint/

using this option will not require any access at tenant level.

Cheers

Comment: Using this option will make sure your workflow gets obsolete much faster. Good job !